# How to add details of two different list into another list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Here i created the three classes and three lists.

I was able to successfully add project and employee to their respective lists.

Now i am creating a new Class and List to add employee to the project

```
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    
    public Project(int Id)
    {
        this.id = Id;
    }
    public Project()
    {

    }


public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }


    public Employee(int empid)
    {
        this.EmployeeID = empid;
    }

    public Employee()
    {

    }

public class ProjectManagement
{
    public List<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();

    //Method for adding projects
    public void AddingProjects(Project project)
    {
        Projects.Add(project);
    }

public class EmpManagement
{
    public List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    //Method for adding new employee
    public void AddEmp(Employee emp)
    {
        empList.Add(emp);
    }


public class AddEmptoProject
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string EMPfirstName { get; set; }
    public AddEmptoProject(string projectName, string empfirstname)
    {
        this.ProjectName = projectName;
        this.EMPfirstName = empfirstname;
        }

    public AddEmptoProject()
    {
       
    }
}
```

I want to add and remove employees to the project

One project can have several number of employees

what is the logic ?

A code can help a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you should add a property to your `Project` class to represent a list of `Employees`, all of which are working on the project. Your new `Project` class structure may look like the following:

```
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    private List<Employee> employees { get; set; }

    public Project(int Id)
    {
        this.id = Id;
    }
    public Project()
    {

    }

    public AddEmployee (Employee e)
    {
        # Maybe add logic to prevent Exceptions from adding identical employee 
        # objects to the same list.
        employees.Add(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want some more detailed answer, can you please provide

Comment: @SaiKiran Since you are looking to associate employees with a project, then all you need to do is have a field in your `Project` class to represent the `List<Employee>` (list of employees) associated with that Project. I don't know how to provide much more detail than that.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you want your data structured. One way could be to add a property of type `List<Employee>` to the `Project` class. Then add a method to add an `Employee` to that list.

An example code could look something like:

```cs
public class Project {
  private List<Employee> AssociatedEmployees { get; } = new();
  
  public AddEmployee(Employee employee) {
    AssociatedEmployees.Add(employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be little more brief about the logic